# Is there a regex function to find and replace with variable

Tags: python, regex

Basically what I'm trying to do is replace`variable_name++`
with`variable_name = variable_name +1`
but the `variable_name` could be anything. Somehow I need to save that `variable_name` so I can use it later in the replacement. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't that what capture groups and back-references are for?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\+{2}`

Comment: @dcg shouldn't `0-0` be `0-9`? Why not just use `\w` for alphanumeric?

Comment: @Barmar `\w` matches more than `[A-Za-z0-9_]` unless you use `re.A`

Comment: @Barmar yes, it's `0-9`

Comment: @dcg Python 3 allows Unicode variable names.

Comment: @Barmar yeeeep. I guess I gave the regex for my own variable names, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group and back-reference.

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*\+\+', r'\1 = \1 + 1', string)
```

In the replacement, the back-reference `\1` is replaced with whatever matched the first capture group, which is the variable name before `++`.